# how to get 2 int and 1 float input in the same line? (python)

Tags: python

I need to input two ints and one float in one line separated with space. but this code takes only the int input, what should I change here.

```
x, y, z = [int(x) for x in input("Enter three value: ").split()] 
print("First Number is: ", x) 
print("Second Number is: ", y) 
print("Third Number is: ", z)
```

Comment: Remove int() before for and apply it only to x and y !?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you convert every part of the input to `int`. So, first take your `input` from the user as-is, raw:

```py
x, y, z = input("Enter three values: ").split()
```

And now work on them according to your needs:

```py
print("First Number is: ", int(x)) 
print("Second Number is: ", int(y))
print("Third Number is: ", float(z))
```

Of course you should do some kind of a type check, like:

```py
while True:
    try:
        x, y, z = input("Enter three values: ").split()
        x = int(x)
        y = int(y)
        z = float(z)
        break
    except (TypeError, ValueError):
        print("Please type 2 integers followed by a float")
```

This will also make sure the user inputs exactly 3 numbers.